kivy - py to apk (buildozer)
For months, I've been poring over tutorials, attempting to convert a Kivy Python file into an APK (Android). I'm using Colab and Ubuntu for this task. Unfortunately, I haven't had any success, and I'm feeling desperate. Attached is a file containing the error report (mylog.txt). Could someone please help me? :(
https://easyupload.io/m/lsrqlg
I have studied numerous websites and YouTube channels. A Facebook user tried to help me via AnyDesk. I've made many unsuccessful attempts using Colab. I even installed Ubuntu specifically for this purpose, but still no luck. My app is not extensive - only 1600 lines. I want to learn how to create APK files and kindly request assistance.

Welcome to StackOverflow. This site works best with a specific programming question. Providing a link to your log isn't useful to future readers should the link site goes away, better to add the relevant parts with details as to what you trying, i.e. what does your app do, what libraries it is using etc. in your post. Saying its just '1600 lines' is 'not extensive' doesn't provide any context as to what you trying to make Kivy transform into a Android APK.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
